# Запрос с исключением MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер. Есть массив `books`, он хранит в себе различные `ID` книг из бд. Не получается организовать выборку из бд так, чтобы выборка проходила без рядов книг, которые в массиве `books`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение. 
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: А как получается?

Comment: Через forach массива books на удачу убираются 1-2 ряда, через unset в цикле перебора бд тоже не выход, у меня в запросе стоит limit.

Comment: Может использовать временную таблицу? 

     $mysqli->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (`id` INT NOT NULL)";
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO temp(id) VALUES (?)");
     $id = NULL;
     $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
     foreach ($books as $id) {
        $stmt->execute();
     }
     $stmt->close();
     $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from t where id not in (select id from temp)");

Comment: alexlz, спасибо вам огромное, долго ломал голову над данной проблемой:)

Comment: @alexlz, а зачем временная таблица? Можно ID сразу в последний запрос подставлять)

Comment: @ВОРОН Объём массива books мне неизвестен, а формировать особо длинный запрос я постеснялся.

Answer (score 1):

Начал использовать not in в запросе, проблема решена.